# How to do string like comparison with redis?

Tags: redis

I have an array of item like `{code: 'item code', desc: 'item desc'}` where I have to perform `LIKE` comparison with them; which is exactly like what `LIKE` works in SQL.

Is there anyway to do this with redis?

Comment: I think Redis only has pattern lookup with `KEYS` command. However you can always implement more complex operation using Lua scripting interface that Redis provides.

Comment: KEYS command should not be used in production environment. Redis doesn't support wildchar search like SQL does. You need to structure your data differently:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7604455/how-to-search-in-redis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no like operator for Redis but the author of Redis has a nice article on how to implement autocomplete: http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/autocomplete-with-redis.html

Comment: Cool. Just what i need.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a sorted set with same score for all the items, then you can use [ZSCAN](http://redis.io/commands/zscan) command to match with a glob-style pattern.

For example:

```
redis> ZADD z 0 one 0 two 0 three 0 four
(integer) 4
redis> ZSCAN z 0 match *o*
1) "0"
2) 1) "four"
   2) "0"
   3) "one"
   4) "0"
   5) "two"
   6) "0"
```