# what is most efficient way to find longest sub-string using redis?

Tags: redis

I have various dictionaries like publisher name, location, etc, which are store in redis. and need to find longest substring from redis, when user pass whole reference string.

Example :

publisher name dictionary :

```
Academic Press
Springer US
Kluwer Academic Publishers
Kluwer Academic Publishers-Plenum Publishers
Cambridge University Press
Wiley
```

And when user pass reference string like,

```
1. "Designing Research on Bilingual Development,Springer US (2012), 203-209"
2. "Kluwer Academic Publishers (2011), Clinical Handbook of Obsessive-Compulsive and Related Disorders, 99-134"
3. "IEEE - Psychological Perspectives on Childcare in Indian Indigenous Health Systems, 847-88, 2nd ed. 2003"
```

So expected output is

```
1. Springer US 
2. Kluwer Academic Publishers 
3. NULL : because no sub-sequence found in redis.
```

So my question are :

1. Is redis is useful for this case (if not please suggest other solution)
2. If yes then how to retrieve longest sub-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I search strings in redis?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401194/how-do-i-search-strings-in-redis)

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't think Redis would help this. If you don't want to implement the algorithm by yourself, maybe some opensource search engine like [Elasticsearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) can help.

If you only want a database, then MongoDb can help you search substrings.